# How to save google safe browsing v3 list

Tags: safe-browsing

I'm trying to download Google's phishing and malware list from their safe browsing API.
I want to use the new V3 API.

I was managed to get the redirect URL that makes the list.
Here is the response i get:

> n:1710 
> i:googpub-phish-shavar 
> u:safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKDAgBEOeYARjqmAEgAUoMCAEQu5gBGOWYASABSgwIARDplwEYuZgBIAFKDAgBENmXARjnlwEgAUoMCAEQxpcBGNeXASABSgwIARDDlwEYxJcBIAFKDAgBELCXARjBlwEgAUoMCAEQgpcBGK6XASABSgwIARD-lgEYgJcBIAFKDAgBEOGWARj8lgEgAUoMCAEQ2pYBGN-WASABSgwIARDQlgEY2JYBIAFKDAgBEMKWARjOlgEgAUoMCAEQvZYBGMCWASABSgwIARC6lgEYu5YBIAFKDAgBELWWARi4lgEgAUoMCAEQsJYBGLOWASABSgwIARCmlgEYrpYBIAFKDAgBEJ6WARihlgEgAUoMCAEQm5YBGJyWASABSgwIARCWlgEYmZYBIAFKDAgBEJOWARiUlgEgAUoMCAEQjZYBGJGWASABSgwIARD-lQEYi5YBIAFKDAgBEPeVARj7lQEgAUoMCAEQ9JUBGPSVASABSgwIARDolQEY8JUBIAFKDAgBEOSVARjmlQEgAUoMCAEQ4JUBGOKVASABSgwIARDYlQEY3JUBIAFKDAgBENGVARjVlQEgAUoMCAEQzZUBGM-VASABSgwIARDIlQEYyZUBIAFKDAgBEMCVARjGlQEgAUoMCAEQvpUBGL6VASABSgwIARC7lQEYvJUBIAFKDAgBELiVARi4lQEgAUoMCAEQs5UBGLaVASABSgwIARCwlQEYsZUBIAFKDAgBEK6VARiulQEgAUoMCAEQqpUBGKyVASABSgwIARCmlQEYqJUBIAFKDAgBEKKVARiilQEgAUoMCAEQnZUBGJ2VASABSgwIARCWlQEYl5UBIAFKDAgBEJSVARiUlQEgAUoMCAEQj5UBGJCVASABSgwIARCNlQEYjZUBIAFKDAgBEIWVARiIlQEgAUoMCAEQgZUBGIOVASABSgwIARD7lAEY_5QBIAFKDAgBEPWUARj4lAEgAUoMCAEQ8JQBGPCUASAB 
> u:safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKEAgAEIydExicqRMgASoC0QU 
> u:safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKEAgAEMCOExiLnRMgASoC0gg 
> u:safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKEAgAEKP-Ehi_jhMgASoC_A4 
> u:safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKFAgAENjsEhii_hIgASoGsALLBeMF 
> u:safebrowsing-cache.google.com/safebrowsing/rd/ChRnb29ncHViLXBoaXNoLXNoYXZhcjgBQAJKIAgAEObcEhjX7BIgASoS0QOuBfQGgwfnCLAJsQmyCd0J

My problems are:
1. How do i save the list in to the DB? Does each row in the chunk file is only hashed or i need to deserialize it using Protocol Buffer? 
2. How do i check if a given URL is bad? Do i need to hash it? 
3. How do i need which chunks do i have?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the unofficial Python client implementation for v3 safe browsing API

https://github.com/afilipovich/gglsbl

Comment: Is there such solution available in PHP for v3 safe browsing API ?

Comment: Check out it here, I just finish the implementation for v3 https://github.com/cminatti/phpGSB